Issues with .NET 8 API migration: string additionalData parameter is empty for multiformdata
I recently migrated my backend to .NET 8 and am encountering an issue with an upload API that used to work perfectly.
Here’s the setup:
I have an API method in my controller that accepts a file and an additional data string.
Frontend (Angular):
Task<ActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, string additionalData) {
}

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
formData.append('additionalData', JSON.stringify(param)); 

upload(data: FormData): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl, data, { observe: 'response' });
}

Since moving to .NET 8, the additionalData parameter in the API ends up being an empty string. I’ve confirmed that FormData contains both the file and the JSON string for additionalData when the request is sent.
Is there something I need to adjust in .NET 8 to ensure the additionalData parameter is received correctly? Any guidance on why this might be happening and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for any help!
public IActionResult UploadImage(FileInputModel inputdata)
{
    return Ok();
}

public class FileInputModel 
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Param { get; set; }
}


[FromForm] is supported in .NET 8 and .NET 9 Preview.



Try to use FromForm to fix the issue.
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadImage([FromForm] FileInputModel inputdata)
{
    return Ok();
}

public class FileInputModel
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Param { get; set; }
}

If you still cannot get the value of additionalData, you can check the details of the request in the browser developer tools to see where additionalData is. Then adjust the code.

Hi thanks for your response but [FromForm] is not supported in .Net8 right

@FullStackFledling May I know which document is mentioned not support [FromForm] ? Please share me the link, thanks~
